# Hash function for strings without respecting char's position

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable

The title of my question is self-descriptive.
I need to hash a structure of three 64bit variables (I'll convert them to a string of chars) each one contains a hand of cards - card game app, so swapping of some chars in these variables should produce the same hash.
One approach would be to sort resulting string. Is there any better solution?

Comment: the only approach i guess would be to base your hash function upon frequency of each character from the character set

Comment: Do a google search for `Zobrist hashing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the representation of a hand is similar to a bit set, it is already unordered. For example, if you use a combination of bit masks to represent a combination of cards, say, like this

```
A♠ - 0x00000001
2♠ - 0x00000002
3♠ - 0x00000004
4♠ - 0x00000008
...
K♠ - 0x00001000
A♥ - 0x00002000
2♥ - 0x00004000
...
```

then you can represent hands using bit combinations, like this:

```
A♠ 4♠ 2♥ - 0x00004009
```

This representation is position-independent, i.e. hands `4♠ A♠ 2♥` and `2♥ 4♠ A♠` would have exactly the same representation as `A♠ 4♠ 2♥`. You can convert this representation to a string as necessary by iterating the individual bits, and adding a card to the string representation each time that you discover a bit that is set to 1.

A representation like this can be used to compute a 32-bit hash code by XOR-ing the upper 32 bits of the representation with the lower 32 bits:

```
uint64_t hand = ... // A representation of hand similar to what's described above
uint32_t hash = (uint32_t)(hand ^ (hand >> 32));
```

> Currently my cards are presented as bytes, but bits in two cards can overlap: `A♣ = 0x11; 10♣=0x12; K♣=0x13` ... and so on.

You can convert this representation to the one described above when computing the hash code, and avoid sorting that way:

```
// Each card is a number from 1 to 53, inclusive
uint8_t hand[HAND_SIZE] = ...; // The hand
uint64_t set = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != HAND_SIZE ; i++) {
    set |= (1LL << hand[i]);
}
uint32_t hash = (uint32_t)(set ^ (set >> 32));
```

Comment: `uint32_t hash = (uint32_t)(set ^ (set >> 32));` two cards (with 32 bits difference in bit position) would hash to the same value

Comment: @wildplasser Why? Suits are 13 bits apart, and 13 does not divide 32 or 64. Generally, there's no perfect hash for a 64-bit number, and the XOR approach is relatively widespread. For example, [Java uses it to compute the hash of `Long`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.hashCode%28%29)

Comment: No, I first thought you had 4*16 bits allocated, but you appear to have only the lower 4*13 bits in use. The suit-shifting is not exact, but 0x01 (card#0) and 0x100000000 (card#32) will still yield the same bitmask.

Comment: @wildplasser That's right, with 2^52 possible hands there's bound to be some losses due to dropping 20 bits from a number. Knowing the specifics of a game would help in improving the effects of this "aliasing" - for example, knowing that a hand can have no more than 4 cards or something similar would let us pick a better representation for the hand. Generally, though, a bit mask and a XOR is good enough for most practical purposes (I am using this approach in an iOS app).

Comment: Yes, this is good hand presentation, but not suitable in my case, because I have already implemented MCTS based bot which plays thousands games and there are many copy operations, so as much smaller is the game data more quickly the AI algorithm completes. Currently my cards are presented as bytes, but bits in two cards can overlap: ACE:CLUBS = 0x11; TEN:CLUBS=0x12; KING:CLUBS=0x13 ... and so on. May be sorting is not bad solution.

Comment: @netanalyzer There is a way to avoid sorting - please take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is to count the number of occurrences of each character and then hash the resulting vector(a vector `count`, where `count[c]` is the number of occurrences of a character `c`). I would not say that it is better than sorting(the number of characters is fixed(and probably pretty low) so you can use radix sort)(but I cannot say that it is worse either). The time complexity of both: sorting using radix sort and counting the number of occurrences of each character is linear(moreover, radix sort and counting characters is pretty much the same thing), so there shouldn't be much difference between these two.